# Can Arlinn Kord's -1 ability target planeswalkers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can [Arlinn Kord](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArlinn%20Kord%5d)'s -1 ability (deals 3 damage to target creature or player) target another planeswalker?

Comment: Always read the Gatherer text of cards, not the text printed on the card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it can. In fact the text has been errataed to say:

> −1: Arlinn, Embraced by the Moon deals 3 damage to **any target.** Transform Arlinn, Embraced by the Moon.

“Any target” means any creature, player, or planeswalker.

Before Dominaria, we had a rule called *the planeswalker damage redirection rule*: it meant when we were dealing damage to a player with a spell or ability, we could make that damage hit one of their planeswalkers instead.

Dominaria removed that rule, and any pre-Dominaria card that said “target creature or player” now says “any target” to remain functionally the same. There are a few other changes that were made too: you can read about those in [Dominaria Oracle Changes](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/dominaria-oracle-changes-2018-04-13) under the “Planeswalker Damage Redirection” heading near the start.

If you see a card from before Dominaria that says “target creature or player”, it now has errata to say “any target” instead.